# Folder and file restructuring of a Maven project in git

Tags: git, maven

I am new to git. I have a maven project in a central git repository.

At the moment the project looks like this:

```
   Root
      |
      project
            |
            src/
            target/
            .project
            .gitignore
            .classpath
            .settings/
            pom.xml
```

I want to restructure the folders so that all files and folders come under the Root instead of under project name.
The main reason that I want to do the restructuring is that the Nexus machine i am using for making builds says that the `pom.xml` can not be found.

I looked at a similar project in git which looks exactly like I want to have it and that works fine in Nexus.

I have tried using the `git mv` command to move the files and folders but it refuses to move any folders. I managed to move `pom.xml` using mv but then the project can not fin `pom.xml` and I have tons of errors in Eclipse.

Comment: Just change your local repo as you want, and commit and push the changes?

Comment: What `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` said?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, that `Root` directory is root directory of your git project. It could be verified with `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` command.

Java project contains 2 types of files - managed by git and no managed by git (which are marked as **Untracked** in `git status` output).

So, to move project from `Root/project/` directory to `Root` directory:

1) move tracked files with `git mv`:
If tracked files are `src/*`, `pom.xml` and `.gitignore`:

```
git mv project/src/* ./src/
git mv project/pom.xml ./
git mv project/.gitignore ./
```

2) move untracked files with `mv`:

Git is working with patches that applied to the files and not with directories. That why git leave `Root/project/src/` directory empty. Delete it.

```
$> mv project/* ./ -v
‘project/target’ -> ‘./target’
```

---

By the way, it is strange that your `.gitignore` file stored in `Root/project/` directory insted of `Root` directory.